# nodejs - use res.send - after http request finished

Tags: node.js, http, express

Im using node with express and I am calling within my node server a http get request - now when the complete data arrived from the http-request I want to call `res.send` with the received data. 
My code looks as follows:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

const x = https.get(options, (req) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', req.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', req.headers);

    req.on('data', (locations) => {
        buffer = new Buffer(locations);
        console.log(buffer);
        res.send(buffer);      <== should sent complete result
    });

}).on('error', (err) => console.log('error:', err));

x.end();
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

The Problem With my Code:
I get everytime a different size of data - basically - everytime a incomplete set of data.

Comment: Best to just pipe the request to your res object.  Then, data will be sent automatically as it arrives by the incoming stream.  `req.pipe(res)`.  Also, I'd suggest not using `req` for both arguments that are in scope because of the potential for confusion.

Comment: You can use `.pipe()` with `http.get()` or with the `request()` library as shown in the question yours has been marked a dup of.

Comment: Also see: [Piping remote file in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432779/piping-remote-file-in-expressjs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Why cant I mark your answer as the solution? +1 for your advice. It worked.

Comment: Your question has been marked a duplicate.  There is no new answer to accept.  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Another relevant dup: [Pipe response with http.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899263/pipe-function-in-node-and-http-get)